# How can I do Couchbase XDCR configuration from the command line?

Tags: command-line, couchbase

Can I create and break cross-cluster replication links in some way other than the web console?

Answer (score 1):

Web console is just UI for Couchbase REST API, therefore you can try to create CLI utility that manipulates HTTP requests like "controller/createReplication".

Unfortunately neither official tools nor numerous sdk support this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Docs about the Rest API can be found here:

Managing Cross Data Center Replication (XDCR)
http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-admin-restapi-xdcr.html

Creating replications: 
http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-admin-restapi-xdcr-create-repl.html